# R: "length.out" argument from the seq() function not working properly

Tags: r

I'm trying to build this function to check the multiples of 3, from 0 to the half of the element "number". I'm adding "n" that limits the number of results that I will get.

```
function1 <- function(number, n){
  half <- number / 2
  lessequal <- seq.int(from = 0, to = half, length.out = n)
  multiple <- (lessequal %% 3) == 0

  return (lessequal [multiple])

}
```

When I run this function with n = 2

```
function1 (24, 2)

[1] 0 12
```

When the expected result would be:

```
[1] 0 3
```

If I run it with n = 4. The outcome is always 2 elements instead of 4.

```
function1 (12, 4)

[1] 0 12
```

When I expected to get:

```
[1] 0 3 6 9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify why this result is unexpected?  The sequence from 0 to (12/6) with 4 elements is (0, 2, 4, 6). The two elements that are exactly divisible by 3 (x %% 3 == 0) are 0 and 6.  What am I missing?

Comment: I used a wrong example, sorry!. I want to get the n first numbers that are multiples of three, from 0 to the half of "number". So, the expected result in function1 (24, 4) would be: 0, 3, 6, 9.

Comment: how about `x <- seq.int(0, number/2); head(x[x%%3==0],n)` ?

Comment: please edit your question to use the correct example ...

Comment: I've just edited the full question, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
function1 <- function(number, n){
  half <- number / 2
  lessequal <- seq.int(from = 0, to = half, by=1)
  multiple <- (lessequal %% 3) == 0
  vals <- lessequal [multiple]
  vals <- vals[1:n]
  return (vals)
  
}
function1 (24, 4)
```

Output:

```
function1 (24, 4)
[1] 0 3 6 9
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have a problem when I try to use this function with a vector. For example: function1 ( c(2,4,5), 3). The outcome is the following error: Error in seq.int(from = 0, to = half, by = 1) : 'to' must be of length 1

Comment: @Jusep In that case you can use lapply, give me a moment please!

Comment: Try this `lapply(c(2,4,5), function(x) function1(x,3))` but I dont understand how 2 can have 3 multiples, instead you will get NA

Answer (score 1):

For most of the cases you can get the output with `seq` function itself without passing `numbers`.

```
function1 <- function(n){
  seq(0, length.out = n, by = 3)
}

function1(2)
#[1] 0 3
function1(4)
#[1] 0 3 6 9
```

If there are going to be cases when first `n` multiples of 3 will be higher than `number/2` you can use :

```
function1 <- function(number, n){
  val <- seq(0, number/2, by = 3)
  val[1:n]
}

function1(24, 2)
#[1] 0 3
function1(24, 4)
#[1] 0 3 6 9
function1(12, 4)
#[1]  0  3  6 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use `%/%` (natural division) and then grab the first n numbers that can be divided by 3 i.e `3*k-1` as we start the vector from `0`

```r
get_odd_n <- function(x, n) lapply(x, function(i) (0:(i%/%2))[3*(0:(n-1))+1])
setNames(get_odd_n(6*1:6+4, 7), 6*1:6+4)
$`10`
[1]  0  3 NA NA NA NA NA

$`16`
[1]  0  3  6 NA NA NA NA

$`22`
[1]  0  3  6  9 NA NA NA

$`28`
[1]  0  3  6  9 12 NA NA

$`34`
[1]  0  3  6  9 12 15 NA

$`40`
[1]  0  3  6  9 12 15 18
```